# What is this chip?

Tags: motherboard

I found this chip in a computer that I was disassembling today. (From around 2000) It was in a peculiar slot near the CPU, definitely not CPI or AGP. Any idea what it is?

This one is made by some company called Delta. Another one I saw was made by another company, but looking it up yielded no results.

[image]

Numbers:
The 4 grey chips: Delta SPC134-0R7 0043
Label on chip: CET 0044-018920-01

Comment: what's the motherboard make/model? it has the socket for it

Comment: picture is not focused enough to tell, really.

Comment: also, check the motherboard marking, it might help.

Comment: Please do some more research, research all the alphabetical strings that you can find on it and list them for us. Those four chips you see on the front for example, what are they? The two chips on the right side, what are they? If we even can't figure out what this is we can still try to look at what it would do. But in any case [we're not going to play a guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), we're willing to help you but only when you can help us out... :)

Comment: zone, there's a button you can push when you edit that lets you insert an image, and a dialog box comes up and asks if it's from the web or to be uploaded from your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That to me looks like an old Delta VRM voltage regulator.  What sort of gives it away is the board slot, though, it doesn't look as "old schooly" as I would think.  eBay [has a ton of these](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l2736&_nkw=delta+vrm) up for auction.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This sounds like what it is. There's a transformer on the one side, so it sounds right.